# vuetify: Fail to select first list item after remove filter

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a list make with vuetify as below.

```
    <v-list dense>
      <v-list-item-group mandatory color="blue" v-model="selectedIndex">
        <v-list-item
          v-for="item in items"
          :key="item.id"
          @click="listClick"
        >
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title v-text="item.description"></v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list-item-group>
    </v-list>
```

I am doing a watch on `items` which is a prop for data on the list

```
  watch: {
    items(newItems) {
      this.selectFirstItem(newItems);
    },
  },
```

In method `selectFirstItem`, I try to select first item by setting data `selectedIndex` to 0, which bind to v-model of `v-list-item-group` like this `<v-list-item-group v-model="selectedIndex">`

```
    selectFirstItem(items) {
      .
      .
      .
      this.selectedIndex = 0;
      .
      .
      .
    },
```

for item filter, I am doing it with `computed` like below, `getTrmLevel1` is a vuex getter.

```
    items() {
      if (this.layerIndex === -999) {
        return this.getTrmLevel1;
      }
      return this.getTrmLevel1.filter((item) => item.layer === this.layerIndex);
    },
```

It is working when data change from `all to filtered` (i.e. add a filter), but it is not working when change from `filtered to all` (i.e. clear the filter), it keep highlight the item I selected before remove the filter instead of the first one.

I am new to vue so I am not sure if I am doing the right thing to select first item, any pointer are welcome.

**Latest finding**

After long browsing with the Vue plugin, I find out what caused this behavior.

1) When show all data

```
**Index \ Item**
0 \ a-1
1 \ a-2
2 \ b-1
3 \ b-2
4 \ c-1
```

2) When show item contain `b` only, it is working because the index cannot be reuse as  max index is 1, so for example `b-1` will need to change the index as the original index 2 is larger then 1 and invalid

```
**Index \ Item**
0 \ b-1
1 \ b-2
```

3) When show all items again, it is another story, because index can be reused, so `b-1` and `b-2` keep their index (0 and 1), so the problem is index 0 actually not the first item, but not Vue/Vueify did not response to `this.selectedIndex = 0;`

```
**Index \ Item**
2 \ a-1
3 \ a-2
0 \ b-1
1 \ b-2
4 \ c-1
```

So my latest question is how to `Find out index of first item?` or `Are there other valid method to select the first item?`

**Workaround**

Although not heavily tested, I find a workaround for this issue, the center of this reuse behavior is about `:key` as I am doing `:key="item.id"` it will reuse based on my item key

```
        <v-list-item
          v-for="item in items"
          :key="item.id"
          @click="listClick"
        >
```

so I am now working around this issue by binding the v-for loop index like this `:key="index"`, this way vue reuse the list item base on the position in the list, although it may cause more updating, but I can keep `selectedIndex = 0` for my first item

```
        <v-list-item
          v-for="(item, index) in items"
          :key="index"
          @click="listClick"
        >
```

Any recommendation still welcome

Comment: It sounds like Vue is having difficulty determining when items have been added to the list (as in when they are unfiltered). Can you share how you are filtering the items?

Comment: @ellisdod edited with filtering login

Comment: is the filter in the same component?

Comment: filter is in parent component, and I have some finding and updated with edit, please take a look and let me know if u have some idea... Thanks!

Comment: Strange, which version of vue are you using? I would try a couple of things to explore this 1) adding index to the loop `v-for="(item,index) in items"`  2)  adding `.sort()` to your filter

Comment: hi  ellisdod, I workaround the issue with `:key=index` let me know if u have better solution, I am using 2.6.11

Comment: Could there have have been null values in your item.id?

Comment: nope, all item.id is numeric